# Sanitizing incoming XML via WCF

Tags: c#, java, wcf

I am consuming a Java webservice from .net using WCF.

I am getting an error on deserialization of a response from the Java service

```
The byte 0x00 is not valid at this location.  Line 1, position 725.
```

I know from some research that this is an incorrectly encoded null, but I am unlikely to get the provider to change it, so I would like to sanitize the null out before WCF deserializes the return message.

Any Ideas?

I am using c#, but answers in any CLR language will do.

Comment: good question.. this only happens on some results from the server.. other requests are deserialized just fine, I will take a look at the encoding although I don't think that is the issue.. thanks..

Comment: Promoted question to an answer "Just a thought. Is this a character encoding issue i.e. is the deserializer using an incorrect encoding when trying to deserialize the message? This may result in what appear to be nulls, but are in fact part of the underlying character encoding."

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. Is this a character encoding issue i.e. is the deserializer using an incorrect encoding when trying to deserialize the message? This may result in what appear to be nulls, but are in fact part of the underlying character encoding.